# Ways to make a function with dynamic bound checking in TicTacToe Game

Tags: python

First off thanks for trying to help out.

I have a TicTacToe game completed in python which you can check out here: https://github.com/Weffe/TicTacToe

Currently, everything runs perfectly fine for a 3x3 playing field. I wanted to make the game dynamic in the sense that it can easily scale up to 9x9 with no problems. However, I'm a bit brain dead and can't figure out the cleanest way to make this possible. The main issues lies in Player.py's function get_player_loc_input().

The way it is right now, it's only configured for a 3x3 playing field. However, I want to make it dynamic.

Original code:

```
def get_player_loc_input(self):
    player_input = input('Enter in location for your move: ')  # player input is with respect to field index location
    translated_input = int(player_input)

    if 7 <= translated_input <= 9:
        translated_input = [0, (translated_input - 7)]  # row, col
    elif 4 <= translated_input <= 6:
        translated_input = [1, (translated_input - 4)]  # row, col
    elif 1 <= translated_input <= 3:
        translated_input = [2, (translated_input - 1)]  # row, col
    else:
        raise ValueError('Input is not an index on the playing field. Try again\n')
    return translated_input
```

My current dynamic attempt:

```
def get_player_loc_input(self, num_rows, num_cols):
    value = num_rows*num_cols
    num_rows = num_rows - 1 #adjust from n+1 to n
    for x in range(value, 0, 3):
        lower_bound = x-2
        upper_bound = x
        if lower_bound <= translated_input <= upper_bound:
            translated_input = [num_rows, (translated_input - lower_bound)]
            num_rows = num_rows - 1 #move down to the next row we're on
    return translated_input
```

A picture of the playing field

```
-------------
| 7 | 8 | 9 | #row 0
-------------
| 4 | 5 | 6 | #row 1
-------------
| 1 | 2 | 3 | #row 2
-------------
```

The way it works is by inputting the number of the index you want to replace. Then the function converts that number to a [row,col] "value".

So for example, 4 => [1,0] 
OR 3 => [2,2]

Any ideas? Gonna go do something else for a bit to clear my head.

Comment: Just use the integer division and it's remainder - e.g. row = input / rowlength, while col = input % rowlength. as you count rows from top to bottom, row will be reverted, but hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a little more complex than divide & modulo since rows are not in the correct order

Here's a generic function which works for all values

```
def  get_player_loc_input( nb_rows, nb_cols, pinput):
    pinput -= 1
    rval = (nb_rows-(pinput//nb_cols)-1,pinput%nb_cols)
    return rval

print(get_player_loc_input(3,3,3))
print(get_player_loc_input(3,3,4))
print(get_player_loc_input(3,3,7))
```

output:

```
(2, 2)
(1, 0)
(0, 0)
```

Note that there must be a problem with your code, as you have a method, a `self` and still passing `nb_rows` & `nb_cols` as a parameter. Should be class members (and `translated_input` is not defined)

Comment: Wow it works! Yeah, sorry if I wasn't clear in my original post of how it works. The function prompts the user for input and then takes that input and returns the "real value" aka (2,2) for example. Thanks for the help. Now i just need to figure out how to check if the position the player wants to insert into is valid. So that its not out of bounds.